# HIVE openBox problem with special character FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-hive

I have the following problem.
In my current app that I have on App Store and Google Play I have saved all of users data in a Hive box called app_data:

```
Hive.openBox("app_data")
```

but now in my next update on Android it gives me error that the box can not be opened when initialized. I have searched on the internet and found that the problem is the special character "_" that I am using and when I remove it from the name and call

```
Hive.openBox("appData")
```

it doesn't give me any errors.

How can I resolve this problem or migrate old data from "app_data" to a new box for ex.: "appData"?

Comment: Quick solution: backdate your version of hive to a version where it previously worked.

Comment: @Abion47 I tried it now and it isn't working

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, just delete your app from the device and do a fresh install.

Comment: That doesn't really solve the problem of how to get your users' data that was previously stored in those boxes.

Comment: I think this was only a bug and this won't happen under normal circumstances.

Comment: That's a pretty bold assumption considering this is potentially lost-forever user data we are talking about (and considering I can't find anyone else reporting this seemingly common bug).